# Is there any chance the sizeof operator returns 0?

Tags: c, java-native-interface, sizeof

I require to return a value of `sizeof(some_t)` from C to Java.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL blar(blar) {
#ifndef some_t
  return ?;
#else
  return sizeof(some_t);
#endif
```

As you can see I must return some value for the case the type is *not even defined*. So what's the best value for that case? `0` or `-1`? That's why I'm asking if there is any case that a `sizeof` operation returns `0` in any non-error case.

Comment: The question is not *what object has size 0?*, but *what does the API expect for undefined types?*.  You need to get the answer from the Java Native Interface documentation.  Maybe a return value of `0` is OK, maybe a return value of `-1` tells the caller the right message... It is really a JNI question.

Comment: Unless `some_t` is a *macro* that expands to a type name, this isn't going to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in C always have a positive size, so no `sizeof` can never lead to `0`.

C doesn't allow empty `struct` or `union` types and also arrays *must* have a size that is bigger than `0`. So there is no correct C type what soever that can return a value of `0`.

Comment: I tried `i= sizeof(NULL);` on VC2007 but the result was 4. Apparently it sees it as a NULL pointer or as an int.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, `NULL` is not an object of size `0`, it is either an integer or a pointer, but the size of that thing has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @chqrlie, what is only true in C89? That objects can't have size `0`?

Comment: @chqrlie: zero sized arrays, VLA or not, are invalid in C89, C99, and C11.

Comment: @chqrlie, you are simply wrong. VLA and in fact any array of size `0` are erronous and are either contraint violation (if detectable at compile time) or lead to undefined behavior. That some compilers like seemingly clang permit that, is only possible because they give you a diagnostic at each time.

Comment: I stand corrected, zero sized arrays are an extension supported by clang, but frowned upon.

Answer (score 3):

## This answer relies on Undefined Behaviour; do not use

```
% cat so30681402.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int za[0];
    printf("sizeof array with no elements is %d.\n", (int)sizeof za);
    return 0;
}

% clang -std=c99 -pedantic -Weverything so30681402.c
so30681402.c:4:12: warning: zero size arrays are an extension
      [-Wzero-length-array]
    int za[0];
           ^
1 warning generated.

% ./a.out
sizeof array with no elements is 0.

%
```

Comment: As your compiler correctly indicates, this is an extension of the C language. For C itself this is a constraint violation, so simply invalid code and clang *must* give the diagnostic that you see.

Comment: zero sized arrays were really meant to appear as final members of structures, this usage has been formalized in C99 with incomplete array specifications that cannot be operands to `sizeof`.

Comment: The [C11 flexible array member](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p18) is denoted by an empty array size specification, as in `struct s { int n; double d[]; };`.

Comment: @pmg, your edit isn't correct, unfortunately. This is not undefined behavior but as soon as the length expression of an array declaration is a constant, this is a constraint violation.